# Vue JS: can't gett array index of JSON data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my project i have data from JSON API and i wanted to view the index of each data.. for example, below i viewed the floors from array index numbered from 0 to 22 but when it comes to view flats in each floor i couldn't get the array index, below for floor 0 i have 6 arrays for flats until 22 all have array(6) of flats so i wanted to view them from 0 to 6 for each floor but i couldn't.
can someone help in this please?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWzCj.png

```js
<template>
    <b-card no-body class="bg-default shadow">
  
 <b-table-simple responsive>
  <b-thead>
    <b-tr>
      <b-th sticky-column>flats </b-th>
      <b-th >  //here i want to show the indexes of array(6) in provided image
      
      </b-th>
   
    </b-tr>
  </b-thead>
  <b-tbody >
    <b-tr  v-for="(floor,floor_index) in Building.floors"
              :key="floor_index">
      <b-th sticky-column>{{floor_index}}</b-th> //here i viewed from 0 to 22 floors
      <b-td>Cell</b-td>
 
    </b-tr>
  </b-tbody>
 </b-table-simple>

    </b-card>
    
</template>
<script>
  import projects from './../projects'
  import { Table, TableColumn} from 'element-ui'
  import BuildingsService from "@/services/ApiService"
  export default {
    name: 'light-table',
    components: {

    },
    data() {
      return {
          Flats:[],
          index:0,
          Floors:[],
          Building:[],
         NoOfFloors: [],
        projects,
        currentPage: 1
      };
    },

mounted: function(){
 
      
      BuildingsService.getOneBuilding(`${this.$route.params.id}`).then((response) => {
      this.Building = response.data.response;
 this.NoOfFloors = this.Building.floors;

console.log(this.Building.floors,"single");
   

    });

        BuildingsService.getFlats().then((response) => {
      this.Flats = response.data.response;
 

    });




    
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to get just the 6th item out of the 22 in your array or does each of the 22 items in and of themselves have a 6 item array? trying to follow exactly what you're trying to do.

edit: i think i might get what you're trying to do. i cant test this on my end, but this is essentially what you need to do to get an array inside of another array. you just run another v-for loop through the v-for before it .

try this.

edit: should be in floor, not floor_index

```
     <template>
    <b-card no-body class="bg-default shadow">
  
 <b-table-simple responsive>
  <b-thead>
    <b-tr>
      <b-th sticky-column>flats </b-th>
      <b-tr  v-for="(floor,floor_index) in Building.floors"
              :key="floor_index">
        <div v-for="(flat, index) in floor) :key="index">
               <b-th>{{flat}}</b-th>
                     </div>

      
      </b-th>
   
    </b-tr>
  </b-thead>
  <b-tbody >
    <b-tr  v-for="(floor,floor_index) in Building.floors"
              :key="floor_index">
      <b-th sticky-column>{{floor_index}}</b-th> //here i viewed from 0 to 22 floors
      <b-td>Cell</b-td>
 
    </b-tr>
  </b-tbody>
 </b-table-simple>

    </b-card>
    
</template>
```

some other ways to break things down further is like this. this will show the flats (or whatever other items you have in that array).

```
<b-tbody >
    <b-tr  v-for="(floor,floor_index) in Building.floors"
              :key="floor_index">
      <b-th sticky-column>{{floor.flats}}</b-th> //here i viewed from 0 to 22 floors
      <b-td>Cell</b-td>
 
    </b-tr>
  </b-tbody>
```

you can also show a specific index like this. some examples.

```
{{floor[5]}} //or whatever index you want 0 to 5
{{floor.flats[2]}} //or whatever index you want 0 to 5
{{floor.flats.rooms[1]}} //or whatever index you want 0 to 5
```

etc.

Comment: each of the 22 items have a field called flats and it stores array of 6 data .. in other words, i have 22 floors numbered from 0 to 21 and in each floor there are 6 flats and i want to show those flats as 0 ... 6 index numbers for each floor

Comment: in the above code i was able to show floors numbered from 0 to 21 but i'm stuck in showing that 6 flats of each floor

Comment: thank you but this didn't work :( it gives me  all building flats which are 132 while i need to show 6 flats for each floor

Comment: the function ` <b-tr  v-for="(building, index) in Building.floors"
              :key="index">
      <b-th sticky-column>{{index}}</b-th>`     gives 22 floors all at once idk how can i access each floor of them and view the array(6) flats of them

Comment: see my edit to my answer for some more examples. its hard to know exactly how your use case should work. but hopefully those extra examples can give you some options to try and get something working on your end

Comment: thanks for ur help ... this gives me an idea but not really solve my problem cuz i should implement every thing in dynamic way ... and still stuck on how to get the 6 flats in the array of each floor